# UpdatePanel Update() causes InvalidOperationException Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

My Asp.net 3.5 Visual Studio 2008 Web App has a Web Page (Admin.aspx) with a button event that runs an lengthy process (30 seconds +) then triggers an UpdatePanel1.Update() to refresh the page.. causing an Invalid Operation exception.

Admin.aspx has a MasterPage

Admin.aspx (partial) here:

```
<div id="Tabs">
    <div class="cen2">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeOut="360000" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" runat="server"
            UpdateMode="Conditional"  >
            <ContentTemplate>

           cont....... >
```

Admin.aspx.cs here (partial)  This is fired by a delegate event.

```
private void port_trdRes(object sender, DataTable dt)
{

    dlResSum.DataSource = dt;
    dlResSum.DataBind();
    try
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
    catch (Exception webex)
    {
        SendErr("Admin.aspx PortTrd Res Exception " + webex.Message.ToString());
    }
    simtrd.port.trdRes -= new Steury.Trading.TrdSummDelegate(port_trdRes);
}
```

When I get to `UpdatePanel1.Update()` it always give me an

**Error**:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how you are debugging the application and handling exceptions could be causing this issue. First hand exceptions are not always bad it is just your debugger in VS may be set to stop when this type of exception is thrown.

First hand exceptions don't necessarily mean something is wrong in your code but that an exceptional (pardon the pun) situation was encountered and depending upon how you are handling exceptions within your app it may or may not end gracefully. I think this is the case in your app in that you are not handling exceptions and the debugger is stopping the process.

You should try to incorporate into your code the use of [try catch statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or try catch finally statements. Especially since you have async events that run for a long duration.

If you don't want to use try catch statements and you just want to suppress these first or second change exceptions from appearing you can do so by going to **Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> General** and unchecking **Redirect all Output window text to the immediate window**

Based upon your comment the exception could be caused by the page lifecycle and the server being unaware of a control as the page is being rebuilt on the partial postback. In your code sample you do not appear to be using any triggers in your update panel. If you want the update to be strictly determined in code change the property for the ChildrenAsTriggers to false for the update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

[Here is a more in-depth explanation of how this property works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx)

Comment: Try Catch sends me this message..'Exception The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID UpdatePanel1 before Render'... but still doesn't update.

Comment: @CraigJSte Updated post based upon your comment. Looks as if the control within the updatepanel is attempting to called by the server before it has been created by the partial postback. Setting the ChildrenAsTriggers to false may correct this.

Comment: still throws this after amended code for ChildrenTriggers (see above).....Admin.aspx PortTrd Res Exception The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID UpdatePanel1 before Render.